# Xamarin Android, Bluetooth conection not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to do a simple bluetooth connection Using Xamarin studio. My code builds sucessfully but raises a Java.IO.IOExeption When I try to connect the bluetooth.

This is a snippet from my code.

```
    BluetoothAdapter  BluetoothAdapter1 = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
    BluetoothSocket socket;
    BluetoothDevice device
    btnConnect.Click += async delegate {
            if (BluetoothAdapter1 == null)
            {
                AlertDialog1.SetMessage("Device Does not support bluetooth");

                AlertDialog1.Show();
            }


            if(!BluetoothAdapter1.IsEnabled)
            {
                AlertDialog1.SetMessage("Bluetooth is not enabled");
                AlertDialog1.Show();
            }

            else{

                device = (from bd in BluetoothAdapter1.BondedDevices where bd.Name == "GT-N8000" select bd).FirstOrDefault();

                if(device == null)
                {
                    AlertDialog1.SetMessage("Device Not Found \n Make sure you are paired to the bluetooth device");
                    AlertDialog1.Show();

                }

                else
                {
                    ParcelUuid[] list = device.GetUuids();
                    String MyUUID = list[0].ToString();



                    try 
                    {
                    socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString(MyUUID));



                        socket.Connect();
                    btnConnect.Text = socket.RemoteDevice.Name;

                    socket.Close();
                }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        AlertDialog1.SetMessage(e.Message);
                        AlertDialog1.Show();
                    }


                }
            }
```

This is some of my Output from the log.

[Mono] Assembly Ref addref MatrixDisplay[0xb8da14b8] -> System.Core[0xb8e6b7e0]: 3
[BluetoothAdapter] 584852085: getState(). Returning 12
[BluetoothAdapter] getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
[Choreographer] Skipped 295 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[ViewRootImpl] Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=599.4283, y[0]=596.4481, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=328245301, downTime=328245292, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }
[InputEventReceiver] Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
[InputEventReceiver] Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: Have you made sure the manifest permission are enabled?

Comment: Yes I have the necessary manifest permision, both bluetooth and bluetooth_admin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by not closing the socket immediately  after  connecting.